# Trigger command on buffer load and buffer save

Tags: vim

I want to write a `vim` plugin that does certain text transformations to the text while in the editor, but I don't want these transformations visible inside the file.

As an example, consider the word `Gnarly` in a text file I want to edit. Upon load I would want my vim script change that to `G`, but when I save the buffer I want it to expanded back to `Gnarly`.

My scenario is a little bit more complex because it will involve an external script, but I want to see exactly how that would be invoked.

Also I'd want to be able to apply this change only to some files based on their extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `:h autocmd`. The events you need are `BufRead` and `BufWrite`.

Maybe you will be interested by `:h conceal`.

Comment: Autocmd is what I've needed. But the conceal documentation isn't for me very clear what it does, or how it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, define your own filetype, e.g. `gnarly`. Read `:help new-filetype` for the details, but basically it's this autocmd:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.gnarly        set filetype=gnarly
```

Then, the *conceal* feature introduced in Vim 7.3 is the way to go. Write a syntax script `~/.vim/syntax/gnarly.vim`. For your example it would contain:

```
:syntax keyword gnarlyConceal Gnarly conceal cchar=G
```

But you can also use `:syntax match` for more complex patterns.

Finally, concealment is off by default. To turn it on, put the following command into `~/.vim/ftplugin/gnarly.vim` (you could put it into the syntax file, too, but this separation is recommended and done by all full plugins that ship with Vim):

```
:setlocal conceallevel=1
```

You can customize the `'concealcursor'` behavior, too. If you still need help, have a look at the help pages, or existing plugins that use concealment.